# How to Sum Task-Specific Timesheet Table by Date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am manually filling a timesheet in an Excel table, each row being for a project task, for example:

[project task; time, date, notes; time, date, notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvHJj.png)

I would like to output a table of: Date, Sum of Time. I suspect this can be done using pivot tables but have not been able to figure out how to do this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you have Time/Date/Notes spanning 9 columns for each task? This would not play well with a pivot table. Why not have your data as 4 total columns: Task/Time/Date/Notes. That would open up multiple solutions such as pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Isolated.

After you set up the title, you can add data vertically to make it easier to use the PivotTable.

[image]